# How do I use MIT App Inventor to communicate to a SOAP API

Tags: soap, soap-client, app-inventor

I need to build a HTML request to connect and get data from a SOAP API, using MIT App Inventor.
Receive back the XML and process it. A normal web post does not seem to work.
Like this:

[image]

Comment: You do not say which part is not working, nor do you show the blocks you are using....

Comment: see also [this thread](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/mit-app-inventor-and-soap/8268?u=taifun) in the MIT App Inventor community...